# Comparing 2 DateTime instances and it's giving me the wrong result

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have 2 DateTime instances

```
today = Sun, 25 Nov 2018 18:59:00 -0500
tomorrow = Mon, 26 Nov 2018 00:00:00 GMT +00:00
```

When I do

```
today >= tomorrow
```

it comes out false which is correct

When I do

```
today + 1.minute >= tomorrow
```

it comes out true which is incorrect. Why is it doing that when the Nov 25 should be less than Nov 26? Is it somehow computing just the time and not the date? If yes, how can I fix this?

Comment: Why should it be less? (Note the offset -0500 on the `today` date)

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Thanks for the note!

Comment: You should probably be using `Time` instead of `DateTime`: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F

Comment: @Max Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `today` and `tomorrow` are in a different timezone. When you add `1.minute` to `today`, both values become the same. Hence `==` returns `true`.

```
2.5.3 :001 > today = DateTime.parse('Sun, 25 Nov 2018 18:59:00 -0500')
 => Sun, 25 Nov 2018 18:59:00 -0500
2.5.3 :002 > tomorrow = DateTime.parse('Mon, 26 Nov 2018 00:00:00 GMT +00:00')
 => Mon, 26 Nov 2018 00:00:00 +0000
2.5.3 :003 > today >= tomorrow
 => false
2.5.3 :004 > today + 1.minute
 => Sun, 25 Nov 2018 19:00:00 -0500
2.5.3 :005 > today + 1.minute >= tomorrow
 => true
2.5.3 :006 > today + 1.minute == tomorrow
 => true
```